# Divide a group of n columns using the the first n columns in r

Tags: r, dplyr

I have a data frame like this:

```
df <- data.frame(a = c(1,2,3,4), 
                 b = c(5,6,7,8), 
                 c = c(22,33,44,55), 
                 d = c(7,8,9,10), 
                 e = c(2,3,4,5), 
                 f = c(99,88,66,44))
df
  a b  c  d e  f
1 1 5 22  7 2 99
2 2 6 33  8 3 88
3 3 7 44  9 4 66
4 4 8 55 10 5 44
```

I hope to divide every 2 columns (or multiple of n) by the first two (or n) columns:

```
df$c <- df$c / df$a
df$d <- df$d / df$b
df$e <- df$e / df$a
df$f <- df$f / df$b
df$a <- df$a / df$a
df$b <- df$b / df$b
```

resulting in:

```
df
  a b        c        d        e         f
1 1 1 22.00000 1.400000 2.000000 19.800000
2 1 1 16.50000 1.333333 1.500000 14.666667
3 1 1 14.66667 1.285714 1.333333  9.428571
4 1 1 13.75000 1.250000 1.250000  5.500000
```

is there a way to do this more simply and/or with `dplyr`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We could replicate the columns and divide in `base R`

```
n <- 2
df <- df/df[seq_len(n)][rep(seq_len(n), ncol(df)/n)]
```

-output

```
> df
  a b        c        d        e         f
1 1 1 22.00000 1.400000 2.000000 19.800000
2 1 1 16.50000 1.333333 1.500000 14.666667
3 1 1 14.66667 1.285714 1.333333  9.428571
4 1 1 13.75000 1.250000 1.250000  5.500000
```

---

Or with `dplyr`, use `across` to loop over the alternate columns to do the division

```
library(dplyr)
df %>%
   mutate(across(seq(1, ncol(.), 2), ~ .x/a),
      across(seq(2, ncol(.), 2), ~ .x/b))
```

-output

```
a b        c        d        e         f
1 1 1 22.00000 1.400000 2.000000 19.800000
2 1 1 16.50000 1.333333 1.500000 14.666667
3 1 1 14.66667 1.285714 1.333333  9.428571
4 1 1 13.75000 1.250000 1.250000  5.500000
```

---

Or use a single `across` with a `if/else` condition

```
df %>%
   mutate(across(everything(),
    ~ if(match(cur_column(), names(df)) %% 2 == 0) .x/b else .x/a))
```

-output

```
a b        c        d        e         f
1 1 1 22.00000 1.400000 2.000000 19.800000
2 1 1 16.50000 1.333333 1.500000 14.666667
3 1 1 14.66667 1.285714 1.333333  9.428571
4 1 1 13.75000 1.250000 1.250000  5.500000
```

---

Or another approach is to `split` the data into chunks and divide

```
library(purrr)
library(magrittr)
df %>% 
   split.default(as.integer(gl(ncol(.), n, ncol(.)))) %>% 
   unname %>% 
   map(~ df %>% 
       select(seq_len(n)) %>% 
       divide_by(.x, .)) %>%
   list_cbind()
```

-output

```
 a b        c        d        e         f
1 1 1 22.00000 1.400000 2.000000 19.800000
2 1 1 16.50000 1.333333 1.500000 14.666667
3 1 1 14.66667 1.285714 1.333333  9.428571
4 1 1 13.75000 1.250000 1.250000  5.500000
```

Answer (score 1):

@akrun found almost all possiblities. But I think this variation is also worth to present:
The idea is to split the data frame in two with even and uneven column indices doing the calculation separate on each and binding them at the end in one run with `bind_cols`:

```
library(dplyr)

df[, c(TRUE,FALSE)] %>% 
  mutate(across(, ~./a)) %>% 
  bind_cols(df[, c(FALSE, TRUE)] %>% 
              mutate(across(, ~./b))
            ) %>% 
  select(order(colnames(.)))
```

```
  a b        c        d        e         f
1 1 1 22.00000 1.400000 2.000000 19.800000
2 1 1 16.50000 1.333333 1.500000 14.666667
3 1 1 14.66667 1.285714 1.333333  9.428571
4 1 1 13.75000 1.250000 1.250000  5.500000
```